# Conditional deployment of Azure Data Factory pipelines to another resource group

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-data-factory, continuous-delivery

I'm deploying my Azure Data Factory from one resource group (say `dev`) to another (say `prod`) using Azure DevOps Release Pipeline as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment).

At any point of time, in my `dev` Data Factory, I will have some pipelines which are ready to be published/deployed to `prod` and some which are not.

Currently, whenever I hit `Publish` on the Data Factory Author portal, all my `dev` Data Factory pipelines are deployed to the `prod` Data Factory. However, I want only a select few pipelines to be deployed to my `prod` Data Factory and not all of them.

I figured that Azure Resource Manager offers the [`condition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates#condition) attribute. However, I cannot use this since my template is automatically generated (in `adf-publish` branch).

Any help on how I can conditionally deploy only certain `dev` Data Factory pipelines to my `prod` Data Factory is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not supported as the doc stated. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment#unsupported-features