# how to export ARM template for dataset in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a need to deploy only certain resources from my development Azure Data Factory to my test Azure Data Factory.  That is, I don't want to deploy the entire development Azure Data Factory to my test Azure Data Factory; I want to deploy only some of it.  So, I need to export the ARM templates of various resources types out of my development Azure Data Factory, such as pipelines, datasets, and integration runtimes.  I know how to export the ARM template of pipelines, but I don't see an option to export the ARM template of datasets or integration runtimes.  Is it possible to export the ARM templates of datasets or integration runtimes?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71082193/how-to-export-azure-data-factory-arm-template-using-automation-script-to-local-d):

> The export template feature does not support exporting Azure Data Factory resources.

Thus, you cannot export ARM templates of datasets or integration runtimes. To deploy a dataset, you need to deploy a data factory first. Without deploying a data factory, you cannot deploy a dataset, as a dataset is a resource of a data factory. Additionally, you cannot programmatically export the ARM template.

To create a Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets resource, add the following JSON to your template:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets",
  "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
  "name": "string",
  "properties": {
    "annotations": [ object ],
    "description": "string",
    "folder": {
      "name": "string"
    },
    "linkedServiceName": {
      "parameters": {},
      "referenceName": "string",
      "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    },
    "parameters": {},
    "schema": {},
    "structure": {},
    "type": "string"
    // For remaining properties, see Dataset objects
  }
}
```

For more information, refer to the following Microsoft documents:

- [Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets ARM template](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datafactory/factories/datasets?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template)
- [Create an Azure Data Factory using an Azure Resource Manager template (ARM template) - Azure Data Factory | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-resource-manager-template)

Comment: Given that, is it possible to modify the ARM template of the entire data factory to selectively / conditionally deploy the content in the ARM template?  For example, can I do something like "deploy only the selected resources from the ARM template"?

Comment: As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56984261/conditional-deployment-of-azure-data-factory-pipelines-to-another-resource-group) it is not supported.